# PHP with progress of methods on page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm creating simple wizard for import and I want to implement notification function with progress of methods. For ex. I have methods:

```
public function mainFunction() {
  $this->firstStep();
  $this->secondStep();
}

protected function firstStep() {
   // ...
}

protected function secondStep() {
   // ...
}
```

And now I want to set on website:

```
First step has been completed!
Second step is working...
```

(Text for loading I'll set after previous method complete and before recive response with complete of this method)
How can I do this?

Comment: What did you tried so far ?

Comment: does every step opens a new page or you want to do it in one page?

Comment: @VuralAcar Its one page. And he want to show message once 1st step is completed and 2nd step is started.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way

```
public function mainFunction() {
  $this->firstStep($this);
}

protected function firstStep(myThis) {
  alert("First step has been completed! \n Second step is working...");
  myThis->secondStep();
  // ...
}

protected function secondStep() {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you call your first function from JS by using jQuery.ajax 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

After you get a successful response, you deal with the client side portion of showing the success message, and proceed to starting a new Ajax call to the second function.

This actually goes for any number of consequent operations.

Something like this :

```
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "some.php",
     })
       .done(function() {
         alert( "First part complete!);
         $.ajax({
           method: "POST",
           url: "some2.php",
         })
     });
```